# Material UI: Popover breaks when using onMouseLeave prop

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I remade the simple popover example on [this page](https://material-ui.com/components/popover/) except using mouse hover props:

https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-dewdney-yt3v-yt3vb

```
  <Button 
    variant="contained" 
    onMouseEnter={e => setAnchorEl(e.currentTarget)}
    // onMouseLeave={() => setAnchorEl(null)}
  >
```

As soon as onMouseLeave is uncommented the above code sandbox will break silently. The UI will appear fine but the popover will not display. I have found the same to happen in my actual project.

Commenting onMouseLeave will at least allow onMouseEnter to work correctly with the popover, but it is then stuck on screen.

Am I not using onMouseLeave correctly here?

If it is being used correctly but appears to be a library related bug, what mouse based alternative could be used in place of onMouseLeave above?

Comment: It's not a bug. When the popover is active, it's in focus, and onMouseLeave on the button is triggered. It looks like the behavior you are looking for is Interactive Tooltip. https://material-ui.com/components/tooltips/#tooltips

Comment: Will use that instead, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, and I did not want to use a `Tooltip`.

The fix is to add a style to the popup to suppress the additional `onMouseLeave()` event that gets fired right after the popup opens:

```
        <Popover
            style={{ pointerEvents: 'none' }}
        >
            {children}
        </Popover>
```

I found the [fix here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/7212).